# Item still adds to inventory and health damage does not show and occur.

Tags: python

This program is a user coming across a troll on his journey to avenge his village's attack, the troll will not let him pass across the bridge unless the user answers the three questions correctly. For each question answered correctly, the user will be rewarded with an item added to the inventory, for each incorrect answer the troll will punish the user in some way, in my program it is with health damage starting at 100 points, an incorrect answer on the first question will result in a loss of 25 HP, an incorrect answer on the 2nd question will result in a loss of 35 HP, and on the 3rd it will result in a loss of 45 HP.
I need to get this program so the item is not rewarded when the question is answered incorrectly. Also needs to show damage done for each incorrect answer.
Here's what I have so far:

```
# Every Hero has A Villain
# Program will demonstrate an inventory
# Troll asks hero 3 questions
# hero will be rewarded with an item to his inventory with every correct answer
# with every incorrect answer, he will damaged increasingly with each question

# create an empty tuple
inventory = ()


# create health tuple
health = 100
damage1 = 25
damage2 = 35
damage3 = 45

# variables for inventory
item1 = ("shield",)
item2 = ("armor",)
item3 = ("healing potion","sword",)



answer1 = "pluto"
answer2 = "toothpaste"
answer3 = "deer"

print("You shall not pass, you must answer my three questions correctly to pass.")
input("\n\nPress the enter key to get question 1.")


print("What planet is now considered a dwarf planet?")
if answer1 == "pluto":
    input("Answer1: ")
    inventory += item1
    print(inventory)
    input("\n\nPress the enter key to get question 2.")





else:
    answer1 != "pluto"
    health -= damage1
    print(health)
    print("Hero got the question wrong, so he lost", damage1, "health.")
    input("\n\nPress the enter key to get question 2.")


print("What do you put on your toothbrush to brush your teeth?")
if answer2 == "toothpaste":
    input("Answer2: ")
    inventory += item2
    print(inventory)
    input("\n\nPress the enter key to get question 3.")




else:
    answer2 != "toothpaste"
    health -= damage2
    print("Hero got the question wrong, so he lost", damage2, "health.")
    print(health)
    input("\n\nPress the enter key to get question 3.")



print("What type of animal is Bambi?")
if answer3 == "deer":
    input("Answer3: ")
    inventory += item3
    print(inventory)
    print("You may now cross the bridge, good luck on your quest.")



else:
    answer3 != "deer"
    health -= damage3
    print(health)
    print("Hero got the question wrong, so he lost", damage3, "health.")
    print("Game over.")




input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be checking the answer before it's being inputted, so your question needs to be like:

```
answer = input("What planet is now considered a dwarf planet?")
```

where the `answer` variable is set to whatever the user types in.

Next, you need to check if this answer is right, using the `answer1`, `answer2` and `answer3` variables you've set up:

```
if answer == answer1:
    #input("Answer1: ")
    inventory += item1
    print(inventory)
    input("\n\nPress the enter key to get question 2.")
```

I've commented out the input because you don't need to input again, now that we've already set the `answer` variable to the user's input.

So each question should read something like this:

```
if answer == answer1:
    #input("Answer1: ")
    inventory += item1
    print(inventory)
    input("\n\nPress the enter key to get question 2.")
else:
    #answer1 != "pluto"
    health -= damage1
    print(health)
    print("Hero got the question wrong, so he lost", damage1, "health.")
    input("\n\nPress the enter key to get question 2.")
```

The `answer1 != "pluto"` doesn't make sense. You've already checked if it's right with `if answer == answer1`, so if that's not true, then it must be wrong.

Hope I could help!